# React get returned value from function with fetch

Tags: reactjs, fetch

With the function `productTotalInventory` below, how can I get the value `total` that I printed `console.log(total)` ?  I'm getting empty sting.

I checked several answers, and tried to understand through [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), no success - Thanks!

```
    async function fetchObjectDetails(url, itemId) {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(url + itemId)
            const json = await response.json()

            return json
        } catch (e) {
        }
    }

    const productTotalInventory = (productId) => {
        fetchObjectDetails('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/subProducts/?product_id=', productId)
            .then(result => {
                const total = result.reduce((totalInventory, item) => totalInventory + item.inventory_total, 0)
                console.log(total)
            })
        return total     <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Return empty string
    }
```

Comment: (It doesn't make any sense anyway since `total` is local to your `then` function.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the promise is asynchronous, so your `return total` line executes before the promise has resolved.

you can await it like so:

```js
const productTotalInventory = async (productId) => {
    const result = await fetchObjectDetails('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/subProducts/?product_id=', productId)
    const total = result.reduce((totalInventory, item) => totalInventory + item.inventory_total, 0)
    console.log(total)
    return total     <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Return empty string
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  It seems like the right answer, I just got an error `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`  because I'm trying to call it from inside a `.map(..{productTotalInventory(productDetails.id)}..)` - if you can help also with that, it'll be amazing

Comment: ah, yeah since `productTotalInventory()` is now async, it can't be used directly. I suggest (before you call .map) trying to define `const inventory = productTotalInventory(productDetails.id)` so you can then call `inventory.map(...)` etc.